# DSPACE: White Screen on xmlui after tomcat's restart

Tags: tomcat, dspace

After I restarted the tomcat service the page xmlui isn't working properly. It just gives a blank page. I'm trying to analyze the log files but it doesn't accuses anything. What log should I analyze?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things you could check. I think the first one might actually be  the cause of the problem.

- Did you create a context file in your tomcat folder? The name should match the name of your deployed war 'url'. (you need one for each war you will deploy, so perhaps one for solr as well!) This should be found under (conf/Catalina/localhost)

But if this was not the solution to your problem

- Check the tomcat log
- Check the logs under your dspace deployment folder (/log/dspace.log.[date])
- Is your tomcat compatible with your dspace installation? (I am using tomcat 7, tomcat 8 can cause some problems)

Comment: Yes, the context is already defined. The problem has occurred after tomcat's service restart. I'm trying to find something looking at the logs but all the registers are from like an hour before the restart. I coudln't find any register with time near the restart... Furthermore, all the registers has relation with Solr and I can't link my problem with Solr. So I'm a bit confused about it.

Comment: And you checked the solr log as well I assume? You can always add your logs (or some of it) to the question. Did the deployment go correctly? I had an issue a while ago where the 'fix' was to throw away the deployment folder and run ant update again.

Comment: I just found the error. No space left on the device. After some clean at my directories and restarting the tomcat the xmlui is working back.